# Ionic Build failed -in 10s (node:15188) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning:

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working on Ionic3 Project- I'm trying to build my app. Getting following error
I used to build for this command `ionic cordova build android`

anyone know how to fix that

Thanks

> BUILD FAILED in 10s (node:15188) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise
>   rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
>   with a non-zero exit code.

and my ionic info output is:
cli packages:

```
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.7-201801172029
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.1-201711081842

System:

    Node : v8.8.0
    npm  : 5.6.0
    OS   : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `node-modules` folder and then run

```
npm install
```

Might be this will fixed your problem

Comment: Sir,I tried your solution. it's not working, getting same error